# How to rearrange a set of html elements while preserving their click handlers? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a `<ul>` with number of `<li>`s each having its click handler being attached on page load. There is a button to sort these `<li>`s. In my sort functionality I have sorted the array of jQuery elements of `<li>`s and then appended them into the `<ul>`. this way the sorting works fine but all the `<li>` lose their click handlers. How do i preserve them ?

```
var li_array = $('ul li');
li_array.sort( custom_func );
ul.empty().append( li_array.clone(true, true) );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`li_array.sort()` should not work as `li_array` is not an array, but a jQuery object (unless you use a plugin). ***Update:*** It seems, jQuery does indeed provide a sort method and it is the same built-in function that arrays are using. This surprises me a little as I couldn't find anything in the document. Does someone has more information about this?

Furthermore, there is no need to clone the elements (which implies you don't have to `empty` the list). If you append existing DOM elements to another element, jQuery takes care to detach it first.

This should work (assuming `ul` references your list):

```
var li_array = $('ul li').get(); // li_array will be an array of **DOM elements**
li_array.sort( custom_func );
$(li_array).appendTo(ul); 
// or $(li_array).appendTo('ul'); or however you reference the list
```

---

If you attach the same click handler to each `<li>` element, you better make use of event delegation, using [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/):

```
$('ul').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    // handler
});
```

*More information about delegate:*

*Event delegation* makes use of the fact, that events are [bubbling up the DOM tree](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html). The code above adds a click event listener to the `ul` element. The handler will be triggered for every click event that is raised on descendants of this element. Now, jQuery is smart and it executes the handler only for `li` elements (elements that match the selector, passed as first argument to `delegate`.

The advantage is that you don't add event handlers to every `li` element, but just one to their common ancestor.
You could also add more `li` elements to the list without adding the event listeners to them. The event handler bound to `ul` would also capture clicks on the newly added elements.

Comment: thanks for such an elaborate answer. Which has given me a clue that my code might not work as expected if there is only a single li. otherwise it returns an array of jQuery objects, and secondly I should use appendTo instead of making a clone and then appendying after emptying the list. BTW what i did wrong on my code was to empty before appending.

Comment: Felix, can you please give me some insight on the delegate function? right now I am looping over every LI and adding click handlers.

Comment: hi Felix, I just tried appying .sort() when I got only one <li> and it worked somehow, i dont knwo why but it did, logically it shouldnt as jQuery returns an object, but actually it is an array, with a single entry, and the 0th index of this array contains the DOM object, not the jQuery but the DOM object of that <LI>

Comment: @Umair: Not really sure what you mean. Did you do `$('ul li').sort()`? I just tested it and it seems that jQuery really provides a method `sort`. I didn't know that, it is not documented. If you call `$()`, then it returns *always* a jQuery object, but it might be a collection of objects and can behave similar than an array, but *it is not* an array.

Comment: ohkay got it, it would be jQuery's sort then. :)
good learning !

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/empty/

> To avoid memory leaks, **jQuery removes**
>   other constructs such as data and
>   **event handlers** from the child elements
>   before removing the elements
>   themselves.

And in your code `empty` is called before `clone`

```
ul.empty().append( li_array.clone(true, true) );
```

Thus you may try next:

```
var new_li_array = li_array.clone(true, true);
ul.empty().append(new_li_array);
```

But reordering them with `appendTo` may be better.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what was the issue but Felix has given a more better alternate to this approach. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.live()` for jQuery. This will preserve the li's click function when the li's are manipulated. To use

```
 $('ul li').live('click', function() {
    // function you want to execute
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery`s appendTo function](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) which moves the DOM element without affecting proprietary data(triggers and any other properties of the DOM elem) from the current parent (if any) to whatever elem is passed to the appendTo(element) function

Answer (score 0):

James Padolsey has a really nice [jQuery method for sorting elements](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/sorting-elements-with-jquery/)